# How to find the IP address of a server in network tab

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I'm trying to find the IP Address of a server in my network.

I only know the name shown in the Network tab.

I tried the following:

- Browsing the list of known devices in the DHCP tab of my router
- Using `arp -a` in terminal
- Using `nmap -sP …` in terminal
- Pinging the broadcast address in my network
- Pinging every single possible IP address in the network

Merging the results of all these, I got a list of IP addresses from which I can remove some, knowing which devices they belong to, but I still got some addresses left where I don't know which device they belong to.

I need some way of selecting a given network device listed in the nautilus network tab and being abel to know the ip it uses.

[image: Current list of devices shown in my network tab]

Comment: I found a [similar question](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692209) at ubuntuforums. Maybe it helps

Comment: did you try nslookup?

Comment: @MichaelSaiz I did now, and it returns "** server can't find ***: NXDOMAIN*  I tried with multiple devices.

Comment: @migrc it did help as far as I'm now pretty sure it's an Apple-device, but for the IP-Address, still no luck.